# How to deal with python optional requirements?

Tags: python, pip

On multiple python packages that I maintain I have lots of requirements that are optional but I do still want to try to install all of them on development environments.

Still, for some reasons installations of these can fail of some cases and I want to ignore that as I do not see the installation of an optional requirement as something that can or should be fixed by the maintainers of the current project.

I know that I can use conditionals inside `requirements.txt` like `optionalpackage ; sys.platform == 'win32'` but still this does not solve the problem of package failing to install.

To make the problem even worse it seems that pip does break installation when it encounters the first package that fails to install and this means that I would have to put each optional requirement in a different file and try to install it individually.

## Update

To be clear, this question is not about how to deal with these requirements inside the module code, that's the easy part.

The question is about building, testing (including on Travis) and packaging. From the CI point of view I want to test the package with all optional packages, if possible (try but not fail the tests if installation fails)

Comment: It's not clear what problem you are trying to solve. On one hand, it seems that you want to install packages which are nominally optional. Maybe use a different file than `requirements.txt` for these, and install them separately?  On the other hand, you seem to be at odds with how a missing required package is handled; but if you don't require these packages, you should be in the clear.

Comment: What do you want/expect a program to do if an `import` fails?  You could always trap the `ImportError` exception.

Comment: You shall think over and make clear what you expect as a result. Currently you are trapped in unclear requirements. Yes, I know, it is sometime challenging.

Comment: I updated the question, nope using the ImportError is the easy part, the hard part is how to try to install optional requirements in a nice way (not failing if it fails to install them).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend combining tox with travis using the package [tox-travis](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tox-travis). You can then use the [extras](http://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#confval-extras=MULTI-LINE-LIST) testenv setting in Travis.